# How to setContentView to a new class that extends view android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two classes, a class called Menu and a class called circleGame. When I run my application the Menu class is started and creates a rectangle on the screen. When the user taps the screen I would like my program to switch to my circleGame class (the circleGame class has the exact same code as my Menu class except it draws a circle rather than a rectangle). I wanted to do this using the Activity.setContentView method, but when I try using that method I get an error saying, "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static setContentView(View) from the type Activity." My code is shown below:

```
public class Menu extends View{

Paint blue = new Paint(), black = new Paint();
Display display;
//Width of the user's screen.
int screenWidth;
//Height of the user's screen.
int screenHeight;

public Menu(Context context) {
    super(context);
    blue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    screenWidth = display.getWidth();
    screenHeight = display.getHeight();
    black.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    //Setting the background color to white.
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawRect(0, screenHeight/2, screenWidth, screenHeight/1.5f, blue);
    invalidate();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    float x = event.getX();
      float y = event.getY();

      if(event.getAction() == event.ACTION_UP){
          circleGame test = new circleGame(getContext());
          Activity.setContentView(test);
      } 
    return true;
}
}
```

My error occurs on the line in the onTouchEvent Listener where I wrote: Activity.setContentView(test); I know I can just put the two codes together to make one large file, but then my code would get two confusing if I just have this one large file later on when I start having a lot of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As error states, `setContentView` is not static method, but rather instance method of `Activity`. You can only setContentView on some particular activity instance.

If you creating your `Menu` instance from code of activity, you can pass `Activity` instance in constructor, and use it later. However it would be better to redesign your code to use [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).